# Spring Integration aggregating messages that were split twice

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a use case where my message are being split twice and i want to aggregate all these messages. How can this best be achieved, should i aggregate the messages twice by introducing different sequence headers, or is there a way to aggregate the messages in single aggregating step by overriding the method how messages are grouped?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's called a "nested splitting" and there is built-in algorithm to push sequence detail headers to the stack for a new splitting context. This would allow in the end to have an `ascendant` aggregation: the first one aggregate for the closest nested splitting, pops sequence detail headers and allows the next aggregator to deal with its own sequence context.

So, in two words: it is better to have as many aggregator as you have splitting if you want to send a single message in the start and receive a single message in the end.

Of course you can have a custom splitting algorithm with an `applySequence = false`. As many as you need. And have only a single aggregator in the end, but with a custom correlation logic already.

We have some explanation in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregatingmessagehandler

> Starting with version 5.3, after processing message group, an `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler` performs a `MessageBuilder.popSequenceDetails()` message headers modification for the proper splitter-aggregator scenario with several nested levels.

We don't have a sample on the matter, but here is a configuration for test case: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/aggregator/scenarios/NestedAggregationTests-context.xml